# importing date and time data into jamovi

Tags: r

According to [this link](http://r4stats.com/articles/software-reviews/jamovi/)
"While jamovi doesn’t support true date/time variables, when you import a dataset that contains them, it will convert them to an integer value representing the number of days since 1970-01-01 and assign them labels in the YYYY-MM-DD format."*

Yet when I set up a simple demo data file in Excel, create a date column and a time column, (format the columns as date and time resp) and then put in some sample data and save as CSV, when I read it into jamovi it just comes across as nominal text data.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?
My data looks like this.

[image]